# Making a residual plot in multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, data-visualization, residuals, mlr

I need to make a residual plot and I was wondering whether I make the plots in multiple linear regression on one independent variable at a time (like making a simple linear regression) or the all of the ten independent variables at the same time (like multiple linear regression)? They produce different results for me obviously.

Comment: Hello - "residual plot" can refer to many different things.  What is your goal?  Also you may want to look into partial plots, a.k.a. partial regression plots.

Comment: My goal is to check heteroscadisticity and linearity of the data. I have ten independent variables and I'm not sure whether to plot the residuals individually against dependent variable or all of them at the same time, like when doing a multiple linear regression

Comment: Each plot is valuable, and in addition you should inspect fitted values versus residuals. But no finite amount of plots will be guaranteed to "catch" heteroscedasticity or non-linearity if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

**To check for overall heteroscedasticity**:

- On the Y-axis:  your model's residuals
- On the X-axis:  either your dependent variable or your predicted value for it.  You might try a plot using each.

Note that John Fox in *Regression Diagnostics* finds that, typically, only when the variance of the residuals varies by a factor of three or more is it a serious problem for regression estimation.

**To check for overall linearity**:

- On the Y-axis:  your dependent variable
- On the X-axis:  your predicted value for the dependent variable

Then you might create a linear fitline and one using a lowess and/or a quadratic or even a cubic fit, to compare to the linear one.

**To check for heteroscedasticity, linearity, and influential points with respect to each X-Y relationship**:

- Create partial plots, a.k.a. partial regression plots.  Each will
  show an individual X-Y relationship while controlling for the other
  predictors.